# Absolute positioning of image based upon size of user's resolution (Gatsby)

Tags: reactjs, gatsby

I am attempting to place an image (using absolute positioning) above the fold on the initial render of a page I am building using React (Gatsby SSR). The issue I am having is that the [useWindowSize](https://usehooks.com/useWindowSize/) hook fires immediately and then erroneously places the image in the wrong position.

My current solution determines whether the component exists in the vDOM and then uses a setTimeout , before pushing the new position values into state.

```
    // On initial render, position hero container background
    useEffect(() => {
        if (elementRef && inView) {
            setTimeout(() => {
                console.log("FIRED");
                const boundingClientRect = elementRef.current.getBoundingClientRect();
                setContainerWidth(boundingClientRect.width);
                setContainerHeight(boundingClientRect.height);
                setContainerDistanceFromTop(boundingClientRect.top);
                setContainerDistanceFromLeft(boundingClientRect.left);
            }, 2000)
        }
    }, [inView]);
```

Obviously there are many, many flaws with this approach (won't trigger on slow devices) - but I'm struggling to think of the most optimal way to cause a re-render of the image.

Another solution would be to repeatedly check if the state has changed for a period of time (every second for 10 seconds), but this still doesn't feel very optimal.

I am sure there's a far more elegant approach out there, would be grateful if anybody could assist?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Well, you can avoid 4 of your useStates using one single useState that contains an object with all your properties. In addition, you should be able to get rid of the setTimeout because using the empty deps (`[]`) will ensure you that the DOM tree is loaded (hence your element is in the view).

```
   const [properties, setProperties]= useState({});

     useEffect(() => {
       if(elementRef.current){
         const boundingClientRect = elementRef.current.getBoundingClientRect();
         setProperties({
           width: boundingClientRect.width,
           height: boundingClientRect.height,
           top: boundingClientRect.top,
           left: boundingClientRect.left
         })
       }
    }, []);
```

It's important to set initially the `elementRef` as `null` the avoid React's memoization and setting initially the value as `null` before rehydration. In that way, you only need to check for the `elementRef.current` and setting all properties at once using one single `useState`. After that, you only need to access each property like: `properties.width`, and so on.

The `inView` boolean is also unnecessary since the empty deps (`[]`) will fire your effect once the DOM tree is loaded.